# How to convert multiple lines of output to a single multi-line output

Tags: python, string

This seems to be a really easy one, but I was not able to find the answer myself.
I have a function returns many lines of output:

```
... if lines[i].strip().find('OPEN_MODE') == 0:
            res = lines[i:i + 3]
            for i in res:
                yield i.strip()
            print('')
for inp in db_status(remote_conn):
    print(int)
> DATABASE_STATUS
> -----------------
> ACTIVE ...
```

The next step is to pass the whole output to another function as a multiline string, e.g:

```
'''DATABASE_STATUS
-----------------
ACTIVE...'''
```

I have tried to use splitlines() on int, or join the strings with newlines '\n'.join() but it did not work out.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what exactly went wrong?

Comment: it returns each line separately, so you need to collect it in your for loop before joining, or you need to move the join earlier (before the yield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking "how do I get all the yielded values from my function into a single string?", then try using `join`:

```
result = "\n".join(db_status(remote_conn))
```

I know you said that you tried `"\n".join` already and it didn't work, but I'm guessing you passed in the wrong argument, for example `"\n".join(inp)` within the for loop. With this, you don't actually need a for loop outside of the function at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: _result = "\n".join(db_status(remote_conn))_. Thanks!